# Found com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0, but version 8.3.0 is needed for the google-services plugin

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

Found com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0, but version 8.3.0 is needed for the google-services plugin.

All the dependencies are at same level:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0"
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
```

I have already tried to put this in the end (After dependencies)

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Still Not working.

It's Giving me one error

```
     Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processGpcaDebugGoogleServices'.
     > Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 8.3.0.
```

Not able to find solution in other asked problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your classpath to point to the latest google-services version - it should be `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'`:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
  }
}
```

This is generally done in the topmost `build.gradle` file.

Comment: There you go.A guy from Google ;)

Comment: I have tried this but gradle project sync failed. and shows this Error: Cause: com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin: Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Comment: I have tried to invalidate cache and restart, still not works for me.

Comment: Great! It sounds like you've gotten a totally different error now. You'll want to look through the existing answers on that question and resolve that first, then come back to this.

Comment: when i build with these classpaths :classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'. Then Gradle build successfully and shows that version conflict error.

Comment: That's because you need to use the 3.0.0 google-services, as my answer says.